# Non-functional IF Else VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Witless newbie attempting an If Else based on entries made on a user form:

```
If OptionButtonMed.Value = True Then
    pp = pp + 2
ElseIf OptionButtonLarge = True Then
    pp = pp + 4
ElseIf OptionButtonXL = True Then
    pp = pp + 8
Else: pp
End If
```

It simply does not work. Suggestions valued.

Comment: are al of your objects of type `OptionButton` ? where is this code placed ?

Comment: Could it be due to you missing .Value for your Large and XL buttons...

Comment: oops - added those, still getting my error, breaks before that even!

Comment: @m4sterbunny please post the rest of your code,

Comment: If you are calling this as a function, but not returning any value, then there is really no need to do any calculations at all.  You probably want to return a value by including a statement `calcCost = pp` just before your `End Function`.

Comment: YowE3K- you are spot on. I thought as the Function exits it passes the value back up to the routine that calls it- added your suggestion and now that works. Awesomeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a run-time error, because of your `Else` statement, you need to give `pp` a valid value.

If you try `pp = pp +1` or whatever value, it will work.

Also, it's good practice to keep `.Value` after the `Control` you are trying to test the Critera. (the `= True` is actually not necessary)

Modify your code to:

```
If OptionButtonMed.Value Then
    pp = pp + 2
ElseIf OptionButtonLarge.Value Then
    pp = pp + 4
ElseIf OptionButtonXL.Value Then
    pp = pp + 8
Else
    pp = pp + 1 ' <-- just for example
End If
```

Comment: I am getting Compile error: Expected Sub, Function or Property
Even if I give
        Else pp = pp + 0

Comment: @m4sterbunny where ? which line ? where do you have your code ? in a `Command_Button` event ?

Comment: Seems to be giving me pp = 0 somewhere along the way. But your suggestion was wize!

Function calcCost(pp)


If OptionButtonMed.Value Then
pp = pp + 2
ElseIf OptionButtonLarge.Value Then
pp = pp + 4
ElseIf OptionButtonXL.Value Then
pp = pp + 8
Else: pp = pp * 1

End If

End Function

Comment: This is a `Function` ? that returns what ? How do you call it ?

Comment: @m4sterbunny please post all of your code, and your calling the function code. And let me know what you want to achieve

Comment: @m4sterbunny - Note that the `Else` statement is optional - there is no point including it if all you are going to do is do `pp = pp + 0` or `pp = pp * 1`.

Comment: Shai, I'm heading to bed so can't stick around to see how this pans out, but I suspect the OP just needs a `calcCost = pp` statement in their code.